# I have one table in csv file and want to make pivot table

Tags: python-2.7

```
user    item    tag weight
1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   3   1
1   2   5   1
1   3   2   1
2   1   2   1
2   1   4   1
3   1   2   1
1   1   4   0
```

when I create pivot table

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.user,df.tag])
ratings_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['user','tag'] ,columns=['item'], aggfunc=np.max)
print ratings_df
```

Output:

weight

```
item          1   2   3
user tag  
1    1        1 NaN NaN


     2        1 NaN   1
     3        1 NaN NaN
     5      NaN   1 NaN
2    2        1 NaN NaN


     4        1 NaN NaN

3    2        1 NaN NaN
```

but I want to create pivot table like for every user each tag is display .
In table for user 1 tag 4 is not exist. If tag is not exist it should display tag 4 with 0 entry.
Please help me.